# jquery cycle plugin links in content area not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, cycle

(I am using cycler jquery malsup.
I have links in the content area of my jquery cycler area (where a photo often is) (links called 'read more') that I want to go to a url within my website.

I can't get the links to work.

My development page is: http://new.bishopchatard.org/New2011

The css is: http://new.bishopchatard.org/New2011/cycler.css

```
The pertinenet js is:
  $('#scroller')
          .cycle({
            fx: 'scrollLeft',
            speed: '800',
            timeout: 4500,
            pager: '#scrollernav',
            pagerEvent: 'mouseover',
            pauseOnPagerHover: true,
            next: '#scroller'
        });
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Somehow the relative positioning for #scroller messes up the links. If you remove the position: relative, the links start to work again, but the cycle isn't working properly then. Try to use a different markup for individual slides, don't use tables. I'm sure it will work out